# How to find intersection point between plot and a straight line

Tags: python, matplotlib, geometry

Hello I need to find Intersection point between 2 plots, one is curved and another is straight line as mentioned in the below figure

[image]

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(lst)
plt.plot([x1, x2], [y1, y2], marker='o')
plt.show()
```

Is there any straightforward way to do it

Comment: Perhaps the accepted answer here will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576527/finding-the-point-of-intersection-of-two-line-graphs-drawn-in-matplotlib

Comment: See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55478030/11292489)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
import numpy as np
n = len(lst)
y = np.linspace(y1, y2, n)
close = np.argwhere(np.isclose(lst, y, rtol = 1/n)
print(close)
```

Play with the relative tolerance `rtol` if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you have a math problem, not a code problem.

### The math

The intersection points are where [image: f1==f2], with f1, f2 "defined" by [image: def f_i from x_i, y_i]

Why scare quotes around "defined"? Well, that defines the functions over the sampling points of your inputs, but there is no guarantee that the intersection is one of those. So you need to somehow guess what the function is equal to between sampling points; that's a problem of *interpolation*, which can be anywhere from "trivial" to "writing a PhD about the optimal way to do it".

I will assume in your case a linear interpolant will do (draw straight lines between data points). In that case, there is an intersection point in the segment between consecutive datapoints whenever [image: f1(x)-f2(x)] changes sign between those datapoints.

### The code

In your exact case, one of the function is a constant: [image: f2 == C], which simplifies the solution. (If it was not the case, you would have to walk along segments of each curve and check for intersections; that can be done in linear time (of the sum of both arrays' lengths) but it takes a bit more coding.)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def find_intersections(x, y, C):
    # Contains numpy indexing tricks that can be hard to reproduce
    # in the case where both functions are non-constants
    ii, = np.nonzero((y[1:]-C)*(y[:-1]-C) < 0.)  # intersection indices
    x_intersections = x[ii] + (C - y[ii])/(y[1+ii] - y[ii])*(x[1+ii] - x[ii])
    y_intersections = C * np.ones(len(ii))
    return x_intersections, y_intersections


# parabolic data for example
x1 = np.linspace(-2., 2)
y1 = x1 ** 2

C = 2.0
x2 = np.asarray([min(x1), max(x1)])
y2 = np.asarray([C, C])


xint, yint = find_intersections(x1, y1, C)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x1, y1)
plt.plot(x2, y2)
plt.plot(xint, yint, 'ro')
plt.show()
```